# Referencing the Compared Variable in PHP

Tags: php

This feels like a really stupid question, but I've always wondered if I've been doing this wrong:

```
if($payment->shipping_state OR $payment->shipping_province)
    {
        $request['SHIPTOSTATE'] = isset($payment->shipping_state) ? $payment->shipping_state : $payment->shipping_province;
    }
```

Is there a keyword/an easier way to set `$request['SHIPTOSTATE']`to the variable which exists, since I already confirmed one of the two do in fact exist?

Something like:

```
if ($payment->shipping_state OR $payment->shipping_province)
{
  $var = $this;
}
```

Comment: You are using isset() in your assignation, does this mean the non available values are not present in your object ? If so, you code should throw a lot of E_NOTICE error code if you execute it will all errors enabled.

Comment: actually, using `(!empty($v))`, just wrote isset for the example

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = (!empty($payment->shipping_state))?$payment->shipping_state:$payment->shipping_province;
if (!empty($data))
    $request['SHIPTOSTATE'] = $data;
```

Comment: In PHP 5.3 and above, you can do:

$request['SHIPTOSTATE'] = $payment->shipping_state ?: $payment->shipping_province;

Comment: And what if $payment->shipping_province is empty? I think the idea behind the code is not to set $_SESSION if neither shipping_state nor shipping_province specified.

Comment: I meant replace the first line of your example with it, not all 3 lines (mistakenly left $request['SHIPTOSTATE'] in my comment as I copy pasted from my draft answer to a comment, should read $data = $payment->shipping_state ?: $payment->shipping_province; )